# German Masters' level teaching (in math), seminar vs lecture

Tags: mathematics, teaching, germany

I have been told that there are 2 different styles of teaching Masters level courses in German university:

1. Normal lecture course - the person gives a certain number of lectures (measured in semester hours) each week and also has an exercise class each week (maybe done by a TA).
2. Seminar style course - the person picks a bunch of book chapters or papers and asks students to pick one of them and present them, so each student presents once during the course of the semester.

Is it accurate and can someone give me more details and their person views and experiences? Isn't there a danger with the second style that if you have say 3 students in the class then each student has much more workload? Is it hard work to do 3-4 semester hours of teaching a week?

Comment: Are you intending a career in Academia?

Comment: @Buffy Yes I am

Comment: I don't have an answer, from lack of knowledge about the system in Germany, but, for an academic career, version 2 has some advantages both in learning and in experience. Yes, it may be harder. The fact that it is more "active" is a plus.

Comment: In 2., do you mean "seminar style" rather than "semester style"?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Yes, sorry

Comment: Might be worth clarifying why you want to know.

Comment: @user2705196 I want to teach a certain load and want to know some views on how each style goes. It's hard to find information online it seems

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, the distinction is not so much a question of "teaching style" but of purpose and scope of the course. Option 1-style courses were typically applied to more foundational courses, Option 2-style courses were chosen for niche topics. The former is easy to scale up if you have more students, and doing the homework will help your students build their problem-solving skills. The latter is helpful to give students specialising in a certain topic better perspectives, and carve out some credits for them to get more invested in their particular niche. This "choice" can also depend on how much money/teaching hours your department is willing to allocate to the topic.

[Edit: this paragraph is based on my experience at a specific University in Austria; it may not generalise] In terms of popularity, my former department had to cap the number of seminars you could credit towards a degree as a Mathematics Masters' student to avoid students making almost purely seminar-based degrees. Even if there are only a few students in a seminar, it's a lot less stressful to prepare a few papers for discussion, then spend the rest of the term chatting with people about interesting Mathematics topics, vs taking exams and having to turn up with solved homework assignments on a regular basis (possibly even in the morning). If only very few students enrolled, some combination of cancelling classes or having the lecturer present as well was often applied, although the specific policies will depend on your University.

tl;dr The course format should depend on what you want to achieve with it. Personally (warning, highly subjective), I'd prefer teaching seminars since you typically have a small group of highly motivated students who may be open to recruitment as future masters thesis students (or project interns). And if the topic is closely related to your research, it's more rewarding to prepare for. That being said, if you inherit your predecessor's teaching materials (or have your own prepared) and the lecture topic is easy for you, you often get a lot more hours out of Option 1.

Comment: That's an interesting perspective. Would you feel comfortable to share at which institution(s) you made the experiences described in the second paragraph? Some of the things described there are somewhat different from what I've experienced (at three different universities in Germany so far, in Ulm, Passau, and Wuppertal).

Comment: It was in Austria, so perhaps that makes the difference. I'll add a disclaimer to that effect, since seminars being "easier" is also a very subjective perspective.

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

The following is based on my experience at the Universities of Ulm, Passau, and Wuppertal (all three in Germany). It applies to both Bachelor's and Master's degrees in mathematics.

**Disclaimer:** While things might be similar at many other German universities, they will most certainly be very different at German "Fachhochschulen" ("universities of applied sciences"). I do not have sufficient knowledge of the situation at Fachhochschulen to provide useful information or advice regarding the teaching load there (except for the very simple and vague observation that it is typically higher compared to universities).

**The role of seminars**

You're impression of lectures agrees with my experience.

Regarding seminars, there is quite a bit of variation, even within departments, depending on the preferences of the instructor (or sometimes the students). Every seminar I've (co-)organized (or attended as a student, though that was more than ten years ago) was based on each student preparing and giving a seminar talk. In contrast to user coffee_into_plots's experience in Austria I have (unfortunately) not seen a seminar, yet, where a significant amount of discussion takes place.
Different seminars might, for instance, vary regarding the following matters:

- In some seminars the students will just be required to prepare and give a talk. In other cases they will also be required to hand-in a write-up of a few pages (sometimes before their talk or sometimes after that). That write-up, if required, might be required to be close in content to the seminar talk or to contain more material than the talk. In some cases, an instructor might only require a write-up if they are not satisfied with the quality of the presentation.
- Some studenst might get a grade for the seminar, others might just "pass or fail" the seminar (depending on the regulations of their programme).
- It happens frequently that only very few students attend a seminar. This can be handled in different ways. Some instructors might still just let each students give one talk, so the seminar ends after only a few meetings. Others might argue that this was not enough "exposure to the topic" or not enough "effort" and will fill a few other slots with talks by PhD students or postdocs or themselves (this can sometimes be a nice opportunity to to give a talk about a certain topic which one intended to learn anyway). Sometimes some of the students might volunteer to give two talks. I've not seen a situation so far where any of the students was *required* to give more than one talk.
- Sometimes seminars are used as "companion courses" for certain lectures. I remember there was a lecture about "ODEs and dynamical systems" some years ago when I was a PhD student. Simultaneously we offered a seminar "Dynamical systems via computers", where the talks focussed on modelling concrete problems from the sciences by ODEs, presenting some theoretical properties of the specific ODE and visualizing some of the properties by means of computer simulations. It was possible for students to attend only the lecture or only the seminar, but it was particularly good for some students to attend both simultaneously.

I agree with coffee_into_plots's [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/195581/135841) that the main point about seminars is that they have different objectives than lectures. From my point of view, students should learn the following things in seminars in mathematics (which they are not so likely to learn in lecture-based courses).

- Learn a topic (i.e., they topic of their talk) in a more independent way than it usually happens in lectures.
- Learn how to present mathematics in a talk.
- Learn who to write a brief mathematical text (if they are required to hand-in somekind of write-up). This point can, for a Bachelor's student, be a good preparation for a Bachelor's thesis, so that they don't have to learn this from scratch when writing the thesis.
- Related to the previous point: Some instructors require (or, say, invite) their students to type such a write-up in LaTeX, which will also be a good preparation for a thesis.

Exposure to the contents from the talks of the other students is also nice but is, from my perspective, not the main priority. This strongly distinguishes a seminar from a lecture which is typically accompanied by an exercise course and focusses on learning the contents.

In my experience, students will only be allowed to cover quite a small fraction of the required credit points for their program by seminars. Most of the points typically come from lecture-based courses.

*Personal remark:* Given the average quality (or lack thereof) of research talks at math conferences, I believe there's a severe lack of training and feedback. So I think we should actually require (or at least encourage) students to attend many more seminars than seems to be common.

**Number of teaching hours per week**

OP asked another question regarding "semester hours". The German word is "Semesterwochenstudenten", so I think the right translation would actually be "semester weekly hours". However, the word is quite misleading (both the German word as well as its English translation), since what is actually meant is the number of "hours one has to teach each week during the semester". (Mathematical/physical nitpick: I've heard people, maybe including myself, say "hours per week per semester", but this gives a squared time unit in the denominator which doesn't actually make sense.)

How many of such weekly teaching hours are much or few or difficult or easy to do depends on a lot of things, including your personal approach to teaching, the specific courses you teach, the motivation of the students, and so on. To give some orientation, here are some typical teaching loads that I've seen at German universities:

- Postdoc, if 100% funded by a so-called "Landesstelle" (which means that their funding does not - neither completely nor partially - stem from a grant): 4 to 5 hours per week.

  For positions which are partially funded by research grants, the teaching load is reduced proportionally. For postdocs that are completely funded by a research grant, their typically is no teaching requirement.
- Assistant professor (in German "Juniorprofessor/in"): betwen 4 and 6 hours per week. (I currently have such a position and it's 4 hours per week, but it increases a bit after the first three years.)
- Associate and full professor ("W2 and W3-Professor/in): 9 hours per week.
- Permanent faculty position, but not professor (e.g. "Lehrkraft für besondere Aufgaben" or similar positions): There's a lot of variation, I've often seen 12 or 16 hours per week or something in between. Such positions sometimes come with specific administrational duties (e.g. coordination of international exchange programmes, or specific organizational tasks related to first year students, etc), which sometimes results in a somewhat lower teaching load than the 12 to 16 hours per week indicated above. Sometimes (often?), research is explicitly stated as one of several tasks for such positions, though the fraction of your time that you're supposed to spend on research in such a position is significantly lower than as a postdoc or professor.

This leaves the question which kind of teaching counts as how many hours. That tends to be a bit involved, and the details can for instance depend on the federal state where your university is located. Here's a rough idea of what to expect:

- For everything that has been said above and will be said below, "an hour" is actually 45 minutes. This applies both in the specification of the teaching load and while actually teaching: courses in Germany are, presumably for historical reasons, organized in 45 minutes blocks. In most cases, two such 45 minutes blocks will be grouped to constitute a 90 minutes block - e.g. a lecture that is scheduled at 10 am will typically start at 10:15 and end at 11:45 (or end at 12, with a 15 minutes break in the middle). So those 90 minutes per week mean "two hours".

  I should also point out that many lectures in Germany consist of four hours per week - which thus means two 90 minutes blockes per week. For instance, I currently give such a lecture, with one 90 minutes block on Tuesday and one on Thursday each week.
- For lectures, the teaching load corresponds to what one might describe as "contact hours" in English, i.e. the time when actually giving the lecture or course. Note though that lecturers will typically be expected to offer office hours once a week, and those typically don't count towards your overall number of teaching hours. Preparation time for lectures is **not** counted, either.

  So my present lecture mentioned above (90 minutes each Tuesday and 90 minutes each Thursday) suffices to cover 4 weekly hours of teaching load (which happends to be precisely the teaching load I'm required to cover).
- Same for seminars. If there are several instructors for a seminar, though, then the overall weekly hours of the seminar will typically have to be split among all instructors. Time to assist the students with their preparation will typically **not** be counted extra.
- Supervision of Bachelor's and Master's thesis sometimes counts towards your fulfillment of your teaching load, but I've never seen a department where they count much (having supervised one thesis might for instance count as a small fraction of one weekly hour in the semester when the thesis was submitted). So for many faculty members the theses don't make much of a difference regarding the fulfillment of their teaching load. On the other hand, there are sometimes people who advise quite a large number of thesis students and for those people it might indeed be relevant.

Things tends to be similar for teaching assistants (which are often employees at German universities, for instance PhD students or sometimes also permanent faculty members).

For all of this the theoretical details and how they are handled in practice can vary quite a bit. Please be prepared to sometimes encounter situations which might seem somewhat unfair (e.g., I've seen it happened quite a few times that people get the same amount of hours counted towards their teaching load for courses which obviously cause a very different amount of work, since the bureaucratic rules are not designed to reflect well what happens in reality).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am wanting to offer a course of 4 hours teaching and 2 hours exercises (like you said, an hour meaning 45 minutes). My worry is that students will not take my module (or may drop out) because it is in reality 4.5 actual hours every week. It will be a Master level course. Do you have any view on that?

Comment: @StopUsingFacebook: Aren't those 4+2 courses (4 hours lecture plus 2 hours exercise course per week) very common where you teach? The vast majority of Master courses in mathematics that I've seen have precisely this format. (By they way, your comment sounds a bit as if you are already working at the institution where you want to teach that course; if so, then your colleagues will certainly be able to give you much better advice than anybody on the internet could).